# NSURLErrorDomain Code = -1012 error

Tags: nsurlrequest, sbjson

I am trying to log into a server, but I am receiving an error. I am using SBJSON to convert the request into JSON, and to convert it from JSON back to a string, and I am using one method to make all of my API calls. I've looked around for a solution, but I cannot find any. Here is the method that I use to login:

```
+ (void)requestFromUrl:(NSString *)urlString withType:(NSString *)type withBody:(NSDictionary *)dict
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:type];

    if(dict)
    {
        NSString *jsonString = [dict JSONRepresentation];
        NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:true];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
    }

    NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error)
     {
         if (error)
         {
             NSLog(@"Error retrieving data: %@", error.description);
         }
         else
         {
             id result = [data JSONValue];
             NSLog(@"Received responce: %@", result);

             [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ReceivedResponce" object:self userInfo:result];
         }
     }];
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Error retrieving data: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1012 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this:

```
    NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:true];
```

into:

```
    NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

See if that helps. JSON is required to be UTF8 encoded, not ASCII.